# Using Sidebar Portlet In Yii

Tags: php, yii, sidebar

I am a newbie to the beautiful Yii framework. I want to know how to add sidebar portlet in Yii Framework. I read the document but it was not enough to clear my doubts. So any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portlet in Yii, is just a widget, that displays a fragment of content. Check also this link with example of protlet usage:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/portlet.menu